# Manage job schedulers schedule time from a java application

Tags: java, open-source, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a java application with many job schedulers. Till date I was using cron job scheduler to schedule and run those jobs.

Now I am in search of the following features in scheduler:

- Schedule (adjust job run time) and monitor jobs from my web application
- If possible view my jobs activity like logs, run time etc..

I am not sure whether cron job can do this. I read **Quartz** is good for such activities. Is it so? or there is any other better job scheduler which can perform the above task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz would be a good foundation to build your requirements on top. Quartz provides monitoring API, including [enumerating (CRON) triggers](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/core/QuartzScheduler.html#getTriggerKeys(org.quartz.impl.matchers.GroupMatcher)), [finding next fire time](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getNextFireTime()), [logging job executions](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/plugins/history/LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin.html), etc. There are 3rd-party plugins [to monitor past triggers](http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/wiki/QuartzExtraUserGuide) as well.

## See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267737

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the suggested link For 'Frontend for Quartz', I feel jwatch or myschedule will be good for my job activities. Can you please suggest which one is good in this to Schedule (adjust job run time) and monitor job logs.. Thanks again

Comment: @Kamal: sorry, I haven't used any of these. I just build my own simple dashboard based on API suggested.

Comment: Its ok. Thank you again. I will try with myschedule.

Answer (score 1):

If your web application is Spring Based, I strongly recommend JMS Console and JMS Integration. It is annotation based. You can quickly turn any POJO into a JMS feature.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. But my web application is not spring based. Anyhow I will try to use this in my fore-coming applications. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using SOS Job Scheduler successfully to run many jobs.  You can adjust times on the fly and can check logs that it produces.  It runs locally on a server and has a web interface that allows you to do the things you need.

Here is their main page: 
http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=osource_scheduler_introduction_en.htm

Comment: Thank you. Will look in to this..